# Jenkins - Gradle plugin behind a proxy

Tags: jenkins, gradle, jenkins-plugins

I'm trying to configure a local Jenkins server for build projects automatically, under Windows XP.
I want to invoke a gradle script, so, I installed the gradle plugin. Gradle is well configured for proxy (it's working if I call the script by console), but doesn't work with Jenkins. I try to inject the gradle.properties with the EnvInject Plugin, but still doesn't work. Any idea?

My collegues that use Jenkins on windows 7 doesn't had this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, problem solved: I set up in the environment system variable GRADLE_USER_HOME, `C:\Documents and Settings\myUser\.gradle` in this way gradle can see the gradle.properties file.